# The Run in Test Rail not include the testCases using includeAll: false

Tags: node.js, cucumber, cucumberjs, testrail, wdio

I am integrating this [package](https://github.com/webdriverio-community/wdio-testrail-reporter/blob/main/src/api.ts),
my framework is in Webdriverio and Cucumber, I use the configuration in the README but with includeAll: false, never add the test cases to my run in test rail plataform.
i use  this configuration in webdriverio for muy features.

[feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mQoz.png)

and in testrail are like this:
[testrail test cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjDJW.png)

```
reporters: ['spec',
            ['testrail', {
                projectId: 1,
                suiteId: 1,
                domain: 'xxxxx.testrail.io',
                username: process.env.TESTRAIL_USERNAME,
                apiToken: process.env.TESTRAIL_API_TOKEN,
                runName: 'name for the test run',
                oneReport: true,
                includeAll: false,
                useCucumber: true,
               caseIdTagPrefix: 'C' // used only for multi-platform Cucumber Scenarios
            }
        ]
    ],
```

The result is: when create the run is empty, without test cases, and when wdio try to update there are no test cases and response with 400.
[run empty in testrail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZYxf.png)
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400.

Please, someone has experienced the same thing, who can bring light to this issue

resolved the correct configuration or another approach

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package you are using, but it uses TestRail API and when it creates a run you have to provide either `includeAll: true` or a list of case IDs which should be included into the run (`case_ids` field in the POST request) - I don't know how to do this in the package, but it might give you a little hint :) Also, we are developing our commercial tool for integrating any platform with TestRail which is called [Railflow](https://railflow.io), so you might want to have a look at it

Comment: Thanks,  @Sergi, I changed for the API, and work perfectly.